# Logstash not storing data in correct format on ES

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

My setup is following:

1. Application is writing logs in a file : file.json.
2. Each line in the file contains a single json record which I want to store in ES index.
3. I have configured logstash to read from this file and store the data on ES.

**But logstash is not storing the complete json record as a source in ES. Instead its putting the complete json in a single field.**

**More details**:

Logstash Configuration:

```
input {
    file {
        type => "json"
        path => "file.json"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}

output {
         elasticsearch {
             hosts => [ "10.1.1.1:9200" ]
             index => "index-name"
    }
}
```

file.json:

```
{"name":"John", "age":31, "city":"Abc"}
```

Stored record in ES:

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index_name",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "eHD8KGUBy7HkgIAhGQln",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "type" : "json",
          "host" : "qa-box",
          "@version" : "1",
          "message" : "{name:John,age:31,city:Abc}",
          "@timestamp" : "2018-08-11T12:35:34.184Z",
          "path" : "file.json"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a filter to treat it like JSON:

```
input {
    file {
        type => "json"
        path => "file.json"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}
output {
         elasticsearch {
             hosts => [ "10.1.1.1:9200" ]
             index => "index-name"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Logstash treats the input as plain text by default and stores it in `message` field. 
You should use `json` filter as @dwjv said.

Also if you want to remove original `message`field (and you may want to remove  extra fields generated by logstash like `path` and `host`) you can use `mutate` filter too as follows:

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "message", "path", "host" ]
  }
}
```